# definitions of the free abelian group

Tags: group-theory

How one can use the universal mapping property of free abelian groups to prove that $\sum_{b\in S}<b>$ is a free abelian group generated by $S$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ be an arbitrary Abelian group and $f:S\to A$ a function.

Then there is a unique way to extend $f$ to a homomorphism $\bar f:\sum_{b\in S}\langle b\rangle\,\to A$, namely, we have to set
$$\bar f(n_1b_1+n_2b_2+\dots+n_kb_k):=n_1\,f(b_1)+n_2\,f(b_2)+\dots +n_k\,f(b_k)\,.$$